# Script to create CSV from file

Tags: powershell, csv, filereader

I am trying to read a txt file which content a list of machines I would like to loop inside the array to browse network files to create a CSV with specific line of those network files.

So basically:

```
C:\Temp\srv.txt (machine1,machine2,machine3)
Foreach
machine1\path\configfile.txt -> Line starting with 'Login' -> Output: c:\temp\result.csv
```

I'm having troubles with the implementation.

Comment: Please show at least an example of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$result = @()
Get-Content C:\Temp\srv.txt | Foreach {
    Get-Content $_\path\configfile.txt | Foreach {
        if ($_ -match '^Login') {
            $results += $_
        }
    }
}
$result | Export-Csv C:\Temp\result.csv
```

So what it does it creates an empty array and populates it with strings starting with Login and then outputs it to a csv.